# Get Specific Value from Json Array

Tags: c#, json, parsing, dynamic, json.net

I have to parse the following Json:

```
{"type":"result","rid":"sample","data":[[{"artist":"Artist A","title":"Title A"}],false,0,1,0]}
```

I need to get the values for `artist` and `title`. Can't figure out the format for data though, or whats needed to parse it in either Json.net or dynamic.

What I tried in dynamic:

```
response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(response);
string currPlaying = data.data[0].title;
```

Error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'title'

---

What I tried in Json.net:

```
response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
List<OrionRootObject> playList2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrionRootObject>>(response);
OrionRootObject firstItem2 = playList2.First();
currPlaying = firstItem2.data.First().artist;

...

        public class OrionRootObject
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string rid { get; set; }
            public List<OrionPlaylist> data { get; set; }
        }

        public class OrionPlaylist
        {
            public string artist { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
        }
```

Error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: @Dalton added what I've tried, sorry.

Comment: Is that even a valid JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it.

```
response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(response);
currPlaying = data.data[0][0].title + " - " + data.data[0][0].artist;
```